# Can the values of enum members be automatically decremented instead of incremented?

Tags: c++, enums

For example:

```
enum ABC
{
  apple =  0xe,
  banana = 0xd,
  orange,
  pineapple
}
```

Can `orange` automatically get the value of `0xc` and `pineapple` `0xb`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the values can only automatically increment. If you want the values to go the other way then you can reverse the order of the names.

```
enum ABC
{
   pineapple = 0xb,
   orange,
   banana,
   apple
};
```

Comment: Thankyou. And if I reverse it, and I tell the enum first number is Hex, can it automatically give all other values as HEX? thank you man !

Comment: @AndersLind: Values are values -- they don't have any particular number base. It's only when/if you convert them to something else (e.g., a string) that a base becomes meaningful.